# Determine if $\sum\dfrac{(n!)^n}{n^{4n}}$ is convergent or divergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

**The Question**

Determine if $\sum\dfrac{(n!)^n}{n^{4n}}$ is convergent or divergent

**My work**

first I started off trying to use the ratio test, but soon saw that $\dfrac{(n!)^n}{n^{4n}} = (\dfrac{n!}{n^4})^n \Longrightarrow \sqrt[n]{a_n} = \dfrac{n!}{n^4}$ now it becomes a matter of taking the limit to know what happens.

**My Problem**

I don't know how to take this limit. I simplified down to $\dfrac{(n-1)!}{n^3}$ but I still don't know how to take the pesky limit. Any advice on how to attack the infinite limit of this and of factorials over continuous functions in general?

Comment: for an idea, consider what happens with a **large** number.  Say for example, 1million.  When you take the factorial of 1million, you'll get tens of thousands of terms *near* 1million multiplied together as well as all of the rest of the numbers as well, whereas for $\text{1million}^4$ there will be only four numbers *near* 1million being multiplied together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Claim:** $\dfrac{n!}{n^4} \geq n, \forall n > 8$
To verify the claim we use induction on $n$.

$n = 9, \dfrac{9!}{9^4} = 55.3 \geq 9$.

Assume it is true for $n = k$, we have:

$\dfrac{(k+1)!}{(k+1)^4} = \dfrac{k!}{(k+1)^3} > \dfrac{k!}{2k^3} =\dfrac{k}{2}\cdot \dfrac{k!}{k^4} \geq 4k \geq k+1$.

The claim is true and the conclusion follows: It diverges !

Answer (score 1):

To see that
$$\frac{n!}{n^4}\to\infty$$
observe that, for $n\gt4$,
$$\frac{n!}{n^4}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{n^4}(n-4)!=(1-\frac1n)(1-\frac2n)(1-\frac3n)(n-4)!.$$