# Determine if $\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{(n!)^n}{n^{4n}}$ convergent or divergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, factorial

Determine if $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \dfrac{(n!)^n}{n^{4n}}$$ convergent or divergent.

I see powers of $n$ and so my first thought is to use **root test**.

I can rewrite the series as follows:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \dfrac{(n!)^n}{n^{4n}} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (\dfrac{n!}{n^{4}})^n$$

Applying the ratio test, we consider $\lim_{n\to\infty} (|a_n|)^{1/n}$, but since $a_n$ is always positive, we can neglect that. So we have:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}((\dfrac{n!}{n^{4}})^n)^{1/n} =\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n!}{n^{4}} $$

How do I evaluate this limit? I **think** since $n!$ grows without bound compared to $n^4$, that the limit approaches $\infty$, but how can I show this? Is there an easier test?

**This is similar to another question found in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025186/determine-if-sum-dfracnnn4n-is-convergent-or-divergent?rq=1), but I simply want to know how to evaluate the limit in this case**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For large values of $n$,

$\frac{n!}{n^4} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(n-5)!}{n^4} = \frac{n^4(1-\frac{1}{n})(1-\frac{2}{n})(1-\frac{3}{n})(1-\frac{4}{n})(n-5)!}{n^4} $

$= (1-\frac{1}{n})(1-\frac{2}{n})(1-\frac{3}{n})(1-\frac{4}{n})(n-5)! $

which clearly diverges as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Looks like you do not need the `(n-4)` term

Comment: I can't count :)

Comment: The mistake pointed out above is still in the answer: $\frac{n!}{n^4} = (1-1/n)(1-2/n)(1-3/n)(n-4)!$